# Windows 8 Application: Icons, Splash Screens and Tiles

Tags: windows, cordova, icons, windows-phone-8, splash-screen

I am developing an application for multiple Windows 8 Devices using Phonegap 2.5. Could any one please tell the resolutions of icons and the tiles and the splash screens to be used along with the naming conventions.

I am using Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate to develop the application along with phonegap 2.5.

Thanks,
Ankit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to read [App submission requirements for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh184844%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). 
 Hope It's help